# How to get date in workflow state when button is pressed in OpenERP 7?

Tags: python, date, workflow, odoo, openerp-7

Hi I have a workflow with states pending,approved and complete, i'm trying to get the date automatically in the 'WO_APPROVE_DATE' field, when the approved button is pressed, how do i implement this? pls help..

the buttons

```
<header> 
<button name="pending_draft" string="Pending" states="pending" class="oe_highlight"   type="workflow"/>
<button name="approved_draft" string="Approved" states="approved" class="oe_highlight" type="workflow"/>
<button name="complete" string="Active" states="active" class="oe_highlight" type="workflow"/>
</header>
```

class

```
class work_order(osv.osv):


sel_states = [
    ('pending', 'Pending'),
    ('approved', 'Approved'),
    ('active', 'Complete')
]

_name = "work_order.work_order"
_description = "Work Order Details"

_rec_name = "WO_CODE"
_columns = {
    'WO_CODE' : fields.char("Work Order Code", size=64, required=True, readonly=True ),
    'WO_ASSIGNED_TO' : fields.many2one("hr.employee", "Assigned To", ondelete="no action", domain=[('job_id', '=', ('Crew Supervisor'))]),
    'WO_NOTES' : fields.text("Description"),
    'WO_APPROVE_DATE' : fields.datetime("EngineerApproval Date"),
    'state' : fields.selection(sel_states, "Workflow"),
}

def workorder_pending(self, cr, uid, ids):
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state' : 'pending'})
    return True

def workorder_approved(self, cr, uid, ids):
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state' : 'approved'})
    return True

def workorder_complete(self, cr, uid, ids):
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state' : 'active'})
    return True
```

workflow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <record id="workorder_workflow" model="workflow">
        <field name="name">work_order.workflow</field>
        <field name="osv">work_order.work_order</field>
        <field name="on_create">True</field>
    </record>

    <!--workflow activity-->
    <record id="act_pending" model="workflow.activity">
        <field name="wkf_id" ref="workorder_workflow"/>
        <field name="flow_start">True</field>
        <field name="name">pending</field>
        <field name="kind">function</field>
        <field name="action">workorder_pending()</field>
    </record>

    <record id="act_approved" model="workflow.activity">
        <field name="wkf_id" ref="workorder_workflow"/>
        <field name="name">approved</field>
        <field name="kind">function</field>
        <field name="action">workorder_approved()</field>
    </record>

<record id="act_complete" model="workflow.activity">
        <field name="wkf_id" ref="workorder_workflow"/>
        <field name="flow_stop">True</field>
        <field name="name">complete</field>
        <field name="kind">function</field>
        <field name="action">workorder_complete()</field>
    </record>

<record id="trans_pending_approved" model="workflow.transition">
        <field name="act_from" ref="act_pending"/>
        <field name="act_to" ref="act_approved"/>
        <field name="signal">pending_draft</field>
    </record>

<record id="trans_approved_complete" model="workflow.transition">
        <field name="act_from" ref="act_approved"/>
        <field name="act_to" ref="act_complete"/>
        <field name="signal">complete</field>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first add this lines for importing packages

```
from openerp.tools import DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT, DATETIME_FORMATS_MAP, float_compare
import time
from datetime import datetime
```

then change function like this

```
def workorder_approved(self, cr, uid, ids):
        self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state' : 'approved','WO_APPROVE_DATE':time.strftime(DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT)})
        return True
```

Comment: nice one, needed that too!